# No Run Button in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-mac

In every tutorial I find, it seems that you should have a run button in the upper left corner by default. However, upon starting up the application and opening a project (exactly as shown in the tutorials), all I have is the hammer icon.

Going into the menu, "Debug --> Start w/o Debugging" is grayed out. I have also tried installing the Code Runner extension to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

[image: The screen after booting up the project and writing two lines of code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observe you have created a .Net Standard Library , we cannot run it . You can create a .Net Console app and then you can run it .

.Net Standard csproj is a extension to code sharing ,cannot run it.

Hope this finds helpful

Comment: Great, thanks! I tried making a console app... It wasn't loading earlier, but it's working fine now. Hello, run button!